# application uninstallation in windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I could see that uninstallation off msi application can be achieved in windows using powershell scripting with startprocess command on the uninstallstring registry.

How to achieve the same for the applications which are installed directly using exe and not from msi file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is impossible to answer as every `*.exe` installer can behave in a different way. For some cases, you might try `<setup_file>.exe /?` and get a list of possibilities from which you can pick, but for others this will simply start the installer (again).